In Apache Airflow, how can I exchange data between tasks in different dags, using the Airflow TaskFlow API?
I have 2 dags that look like this (note that the 2nd dag automatically runs after the first - they are linked by an Airflow Dataset). Is there a way for the 2nd dag to retrieve the value returned by the first dag's push_data task?
(Right now what I receive is '{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='push_data', dag_id='xcom_test_start', key='return_value') }}')
uiflow_xcom_test_dataset = Dataset("uiflow_xcom_test")

@dag(
    dag_id="xcom_test_start",
    default_args=default_dag_arguments,
    schedule_interval="@once",
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2024, 1, 1, tz="US/Eastern"),
)
def xcom_test_start():

    @task(outlets=[ uiflow_xcom_test_dataset ])
    def push_data():

        return "sample data"

    push_data()

first_dag = xcom_test_start()


@dag(
    dag_id="xcom_test_end",
    default_args=default_dag_arguments,
    schedule=[ uiflow_xcom_test_dataset ],
    tags=["utility"]
)
def xcom_test_end():

    @task
    def pull_data():

        data = first_dag.tasks[0].output

        print(f"data pulled is {data}")

    pull_data()

xcom_test_end()


You may use xcom_pull instead of "first_dag.tasks[0].output", like
    @task()
    def pull_data(**kwargs):
        # Pull data from XCom
        ti = kwargs['ti']
        data = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='push_data', dag_id='xcom_test_start')
        print(f"data pulled is {data}")

The whole code for second dag likes
@dag(
    dag_id="xcom_test_end",
    default_args=default_dag_arguments,
    schedule_interval="@once",  # Schedule accordingly
    tags=["utility"]
)
def xcom_test_end():

    @task()
    def pull_data(**kwargs):
        # Pull data from XCom
        ti = kwargs['ti']
        data = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='push_data', dag_id='xcom_test_start')
        print(f"data pulled is {data}")

    # Call the pull_data task
    pull_data_task = pull_data()

    return pull_data_task


second_dag = xcom_test_end()


thanks - I am getting the same result from that, too, though (i.e., no data transferred) - INFO - data pulled is None

I found that the best (best meaning the only way I found to work) way to transfer data between Dags is by use of variables:
from airflow.models import Variable

# Setting the variable you want (try to keep to a json format)
Variable.set(key = YOUR_KEY_HERE, value = YOUR_VALUE_HERE)

# Retrieving the variable (default_var means this is what will be returned 
# if there is no variable found with that key)
Variable.get(key = YOUR_KEY_HERE, default_var = YOUR_DEFAULT_VARIABLE_HERE)

If you're having issues with the formatting when retrieving data in json format you can try adding this argument to the get and set function calls:
deserialize_json = True

The idea being that you set the variable with one dag and then retrieve that variable with the second. If you wish to clean up after the dag you can add a third variable call to delete said variable:
Variable.delete(key = YOUR_KEY_HERE)

